# How to find music at 60/90/180 bpm to sync with exercise?

Tags: music, music-recognition

(I've posted this elsewhere, at [fitness SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32419/how-to-find-music-at-60-90-180-bpm-to-sync-with-exercise), but perhaps it's most likely to find an answer here).

I follow the recommendation that it's good practice to run with a close to 170/180 bpm pace, at any speed (slow or fast). That is, when running you should be hitting the floor around 180 times per minute. I understand this bpm timing is also recommendable for riding a bicycle.
 
One available resource to get to this pace is metronome software, this is often included in the features of different (gps) watches.

The broader question is if it's possible to find songs that have a specific rhythm. There's a site that does this for you: [jog.fm](https://cycle.jog.fm/), but this just offers song by song ideas.

**Is there a program that selects songs with a specific beat from a music collection**?
Either from my hard drive directly, or online music.

Another answer suggests that there's even a certain [*music genre* that is set at a certain beat](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4525/list-of-average-genre-tempo-bpm-levels?noredirect=1&lq=1). Perhaps there's a set of LPs/CDs that have this pace?
I think perhaps something by *Kraftwerk*, but just guessing.

---

*Semi-self answer*:
Seems that what I'm looking for is very close to this DJ program called [mixxx](http://mixxx.org/), but I can't quite handle it, so I'm not sure if it works properly (Any ideas on how to configure sound and make it play)?

Comment: How exact do you need it?  Two alternatives:  grab everything from 160 to 200 bpm and speed-shift the songs via Audacity or similar tool (change bpm, NOT the song pitch).  Or,  grab stuff at, say, half the bpm and do two steps per beat.

Comment: Related question : [Software to detect BPM and tag MP3 files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/software-to-detect-bpm-and-tag-mp3-files)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the Spotify Running feature? I haven't used it but it claims to select music based on your running tempo which I think is kind of what you're looking for. You can find it under Genres as Running.

Comment: @Thomas that actually seems very useful. However, that is more of a _streaming_ system. In some way it's similar to jog.fm. What I'm looking for is rather a way, through (preferably open source) _software in my pc_, to have control and knowledge on music that I have available in my own computer. And idealy to find some LPs at a certain rate. Also, spotify running, [ indicates in this video that it matches to your running bpm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fZBqV_yMq4), and not the other way around. In sum, **I look for a musical metronome** with a beat to which I should adapt.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a good number of programs like what you are looking for. Try searching for tempo music program or app. I googled tempo music app and found Tempo Magic Pro for iPhone. I've never used it but they advertise it as meant for exercise. It will adjust the tempo of your iPod music to match the bpm you want.

Comment: "`I think there are a good number of programs like what you are looking for. Try searching for tempo music program or app. I googled  ... I've never used it`" - this is a very poor quality "answer". We can assume that the OP knows how to use Google & has done so before coming here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only listening to music without vocals, I will suggest you to take any track in the +_ 30 range, put it in any Audio editing software like abelton, acid music studio and render that track at whatever BPM you want. That can be another alternative.